# PyQt5: bring child windows to front, if main window is brought in front

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have written this code for the behaviour of my parent window and its children (which belong to self.windowList). I wanted all child windows to minimise if the parent is minimised:

```
    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & Qt.WindowMinimized:
                for i in range(len(self.windowList)):
                    self.windowList[i].showMinimized()
            else:
                for i in range(len(self.windowList)):
                    self.windowList[i].showNormal()
```

now I want to achieve the same behaviour for this instance: if all my application windows are brought to foreground and then I click on something else (e.g. Safari, whatever else), so the windows are all behind safari, but then if I click on my parent window, all child windows should also come back to the front. Is there equivalent of the code I wrote above for such behaviour? I do not know and couldn't find what window state would mean that the window has been brought to foreground. I've tried several possibilities, including activateWindow for children when parent is active, but what that does is also restores them from being minimised, which is not the behaviour I want.

Comment: provide a [mcve]